# Error when uploading package to CRAN incoming: 550 access denied

Tags: r, ftp, cran

I'm trying to upload a package on CRAN for its first release, but I can't get past the FTP upload.

It seems I do not have write access to ftp://cran.r-project.org/incoming:

```
550 Access is denied.
Could not download /home/roudierp/Documents/CODE/lhs/fresh_meat/clhs_0.4-2.tar.gz from local filesystem
There were 1 files or directories that could not be transferred. Check the log for which items were not properly transferred.
```

I tried with two file browsers (Dolphin and Konqueror), two GUI-based FTP clients (FireFTP and GFTP) and with good ol' `ftp` command line interface, with no success.

I used `anonymous` as the user name, and my email address or nothing at all as passwords.

I also tried to use `curl` and explicitly disable EPSV as per [this post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2006-August/038753.html):

```
curl --disable-epsv -T clhs_0.4-2.tar.gz ftp://cran.R-project.org/incoming/
```

But I still get an access denial error:

```
curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 550
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think the login name should be "anonymous": what did you use? If you do not specify it, most FTP clients will use your current login name.

Comment: Thanks - I used `anonymous`. Good point though, I edited my question.

Comment: I just uploaded my package to CRAN using gFTP and it worked fine. Did you try it again? There could have been a small period of downtime in service, even though you could connect.

Comment: I tried again this morning (NZ time) using gFTP (among others), unsuccessfully. It seems to be a problem on my side thought, as other contributors seem to have uploaded archives on `incoming` without apparent trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally managed to upload my package: as expected, it was a problem on my side.

It seems that the proxy behind which I am while at work would be to blame, and somehow blocked the upload. Weird stuff, as I've been uploading stuff to external FTP sites in the past, and as I'm pretty sure port 21 is not blocked.

But anyway, I managed to upload my archive to `ftp://cran.R-project.org/incoming/`
 from a direct internet connection whithout problem.

Thanks,

Pierre